# How can I open an .mht file in linux (Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mht

How can I open an .mht file in linux (Ubuntu)?

Comment: Drag and drop to chrome works.

Answer (score 14):

.mht stands for [MHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML) (MIME HTML). Internet Explorer uses this to save a web page and dependent files into one file.

To open these in Ubuntu, you need a special program. The Wikipedia entry lists a few:

> Mozilla Firefox needs UnMHT or Mozilla
>   Archive Format extensions to open and
>   write MHT files. These add-ons work
>   with Firefox 1.0 and later. Since
>   version 5.0.0, UnMHT offers partial
>   support for MHT files exported from
>   Microsoft Office applications. Mozilla
>   Archive Format, as well as opening and
>   saving .mht files, also can save to
>   its own "MAFF" format. The MHT files
>   it generates are not fully compatible
>   with Microsoft's products.[3]
>
> Currently Firefox doesn't include
>   support for saving or opening web
>   pages as MHTML files without either of
>   these add-ons, as of version 3.5.2.
>   There is, however, source code
>   available for viewing MHTML files
>   within the related Thunderbird
>   project, so in the future it may
>   become available without such add-ons.
>   This is filed as an unsolved issue
>   within the Firefox project since 1999
>   (see bug 18764) though progress in
>   fixing it seems to have stalled.

UnMHT is [available here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/unmht/).

Comment: Direct link to addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/unmht/ .

Comment: UnMHT seemed not to work to open MHT file generated by PSR.exe on a windows 7 rig (No Images, lots of inline XML shown) :(

Comment: Opens in chrome

Comment: Cheers from 2020. UnMHT is now dead :(

Comment: @AramParonikyan On Linux, I just unpacked a .mht (20211116.mht) produced by OneNote by (careful you might suppress `| sh` to proofread it): `munpack 20211116.mht ; grep 'Content-Location: file://' 20211116.mht | sed 's_^Content-Location:\s*file:///\(.*\)/[^/]*$_mkdir -p \1 _g' | uniq | sh ; grep 'Content-Location: file://' 20211116.mht | sed -e '1d' -e '$d' -e 's/.$//' | cat -n | sed 's:^\s*\([0-9][0-9]*\)\s*Content-Location\:\s*file\:///:mv part\1 :g' | sh ; grep 'Content-Location: file://' 20211116.mht | head -n 1 | sed -e 's:Content-Location\:\s*file\:///:mv part1.desc :g' -e 's/.$//' | sh`

Answer (score 10):

Google Chrome can open MHTML, I checked.

Comment: it does, however i don't get the images

Comment: Yeah, it does if you drag the .mhtml file from the files app to the Chrome app. But if you just double click on it, it says "There is no application installed for "MHTML web archive" files. Do you want to search for an application to open this file?" If you say yes, it offers to install Falkon or GNOME Web, but gives no option to associate it with Chrome. How do you get it to just automatically open in Chrome?

Comment: One way to get it to open in Chrome is to right click, select "Open with Other Application", click "View All Applications", then select Chrome (or Chromium, etc.). It remembered my choice, so now I can simply double click on an .mhtml file and it will open it in the same app.

Comment: :-( chrome doesnt open mht as of today

Comment: Not on Feb 2021, on  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Chrome Version 88.0.4324.150 (Official Build) (64-bit)). I checked.

Answer (score 4):

Simply install Opera and it handles it without requring any plugin. But of course, Opera is not really fashionable these days.

Comment: I had to save each image manually, but they did appear to be full resolution. Saving the page as a web archive seemed to just not work, but viewing the mht worked just fine.

Comment: This was the fastest solution. Firefox Quantum doesn't like the addon provided by @sleske

Answer (score 2):

If you want .mhtml files to just automatically open in Chrome if you double click on them:

- right click on the file
- select "Open with Other Application"
- click "View All Applications"
- then select Chrome (or Chromium, etc.) and click the Select button

It remembered my choice, so now I can simply double click on an .mhtml file and it will open it in the same app.

Answer (score 2):

Both the suggested Firefox browser extensions are dead (UnMHT and Mozilla Archive Formats).
But other **browsers based on Chromium engine** can still open MHT files.
I did it with Vivaldi browser.

Comment: i tried with Opera and Vivaldi and both failed to open mht. So the question is still open : how can .mht files be opened ?

Answer (score 0):

**Chrome can open it**, you just need to drap the file to chrome window or open it with chrome!

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I used GHex; found the URL in the beginning, and then my Ubuntu 20.04 standard web browser opened it with Internet connection.